# Java unreported Exception error

Tags: java, exception, compiler-errors

I have a method which adds two vectors together and I need to return an exception if the length of these vectors are not the same to start off with.
I have written a code

```
public static Vector  vectorAdd(Vector v1, Vector v2) throws IllegalOperandException{
    if(v1.getLength() == v2.getLength()) {
        double[] temp = new double[v1.getLength()];
        for(int i = 0; i < temp.length; i++) {
            temp[i] = v1.get(i) + v2.get(i);
        }
        Vector v3 = new Vector(temp);
        return v3;
    } else {
        throw new IllegalOperandException("Length of Vectors Differ");
    }
}
```

But once I compile my main method

```
else if (userInput == 2) {
            System.out.println("Please enter a vector!");
            System.out.println("Separate vector components by "
                + "using a space.");
            Vector v1 = input.readVector();
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println("Please enter a vector!");
            System.out.println("Separate vector components by "
                + "using a space.");
            Vector v2 = input.readVector();
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println(LinearAlgebra.VectorAdd(v1, v2));
```

There is an error of

error: unreported exception IllegalOperandException; must be caught or declared to be thrown
                System.out.println(LinearAlgebra.vectorAdd(v1, v2));

I have been googling for an hour now, but I do not get what is the problem.
I'm pretty sure it's something related with try and catch, but I have no idea how to fix it.
What should I do?

Comment: you have throw  exception IllegalOperandException.so you need to handle exception

Comment: Try surrounding that System.out.println(LinearAlgebra blah blah) with a try/catch block that specifically handles IllegalOperandException or generically, handles Exception.

Comment: @MarsAtomic http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2416316/why-is-the-catchexception-almost-always-a-bad-idea

Comment: This may be useful: [What are checked exceptions?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9371686/what-are-checked-exceptions-in-java-c)

Comment: @m0skit0 Good point. I was thinking about a temporary way around the issue while the code was being crafted, but it's never too early to exhibit good form.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whenever you do something that can throw a particular type of `Exception`, you have to have something in place to deal with it. This can be either of two things:

1. surround it with a `try`/`catch` block;
2. add the `Exception` type to the `throws` clause of your method.

In your case, you're invoking the `LinearAlgebra.vectorAdd()` method, and that method can throw an `IllegalOperandException` (presumably if one of its arguments is dodgy). That means that the method in which you invoke it can also throw that exception. Either catch it, or add `throws IllegalOperandException` to the signature of the method in which that line occurs. Sounds as though it's your `main` method, so it would become

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IllegalOperandException {
    //...
}
```

This is called *letting the exception propagate upwards*.

To catch the exception instead, you'd have

```
try {
    System.out.println(LinearAlgebra.VectorAdd(v1, v2));
} catch (IllegalOperandException e) {
    // do something with the exception, for instance:
    e.printStackTrace();
    // maybe do something to log it to a file, or whatever...
    // or you might be able to recover gracefully...
    // or if there's just nothing you can do about it, then you might:
    System.exit(1);
}
```

That will allow you to deal with it when it happens. It enables you to return some specific result instead if it all goes wrong, or (in this case) print an error and terminate the program.